# Google Stackdriver Monitoring to monitor each VM in a Instance Group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

We are using Managed Instance Group(MIG) in Google Cloud Platform. I have installed agent via a startup script, so it is able to send metrics

Requirement: Monitor VM disk utilisation for each instance in MIG and send alerts.

When a deployment is performed/ when the new VMs get created when there is a process of scaling, I have to filter each VMs after the deployment or for the newly created VM.

Is there a way to dynamically monitor VMs when we perform rolling replacements or for the newly created VM to create a chart?

Comment: Please clarify - you have v1 instances and monitoring them. Then you do a rolling update and anfter a time you have v2 instances and want to monitor only v2 ones and stop v1's ? In this case while rolling update is happening you will have v1 and v2 instances monitored at the same time. Or do you want to stop monitoring v1's the moment the update starts ?

Comment: Yes. After the rolling update, no need to monitor v1 instances.

So now this is what I am doing,
After the update, I need to change the filter from pointing to the v1 instances to the v2 instances. If I have 5 v1 instances and a chart for each instance, I should update the filter after rolling update to v2 instances for each chart.

I am trying to find a way were the instances in chart are auto updated with the v2 ones

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact chart configuration ?

Comment: What is your goal here ? If you're using MIG then if for example any of your VM's will stop responding it will be replaced by a new one so monitoring disk space seems odd.. You can create resource group that will be monitored and the new VM's after the update will be included in it. However it doesn't work exactly the same way you want it.